# Hiding protected fields from Jackson serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

For some reason I am not able to hide protected fields (without setter), via `ObjectMapper` configuration, from being serialized to a JSON string.

My POJO:

```java
public class Item {

    protected String sn;
    private String name;

    public Item(){
        sn = "43254667";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSn() {
        return sn;
    }

}
```

My mapper:

```json
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.NONE);
```

The output is:

```json
{
  "sn" : "43254667",
  "name" : "abc"
}
```

**UPDATE:** I cannot modify the `Item` class, hence I cannot use annotations.

Comment: Have you considered annotation them with `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: did you try `jsonignore` annotation refer http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/10/jackson-json-difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonignoreproperties-annotations/

Comment: Please see my update, sorry for confusion.

Comment: You are setting the visibility for the _getter_ to public only. The getter for sn is public, so it picks it up.

Comment: I can't change the pojo class, is there a configuration for this scenario?

Comment: Use field accessors or custom serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `@JsonIgnore`

You could annotate the field or method with [`@JsonIgnore`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

It's a marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field is to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality.

Use as following:

```java
public class Item {

    @JsonIgnore
    protected String sn;

    ...
}
```

Or as following:

```java
public class Item {

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getSn() {
        return sn;
    }
}
```

### Use `@JsonIgnore` with mix-ins

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605127/hiding-protected-fields-from-jackson-serialization/43605171#comment74259734_43605171), you could use mix-in annotations when modifying the classes is not an option, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889775/1426227).

You can think of it as kind of aspect-oriented way of adding more annotations during runtime, to augment statically defined ones.

First, define a mix-in annotation interface (class would do as well):

```java
public interface ItemMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore
    String getSn();
}
```

Then configure your [`ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to use the defined interface as a mix-in for your POJO:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(Item.class, ItemMixIn.class);
```

For extra details, check the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

### Use a `BeanSerializerModifier`

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605127/hiding-protected-fields-from-jackson-serialization/43605171?noredirect=1#comment74261077_43605171), you may consider a [`BeanSerializerModifier`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html), as following:

```java
public class CustomSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config,
        BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {

        // In this method you can add, remove or replace any of passed properties

        return beanProperties;
    }
}
```

Then register the custom serializer as a module in your [`ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule() {

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new CustomSerializerModifier());
    }
});
```

Comment: you beat me for fraction of second :p

Comment: @AmitK I've just seen your comment. Actually 19 seconds!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I can't use annotation.

Comment: @yuris , thats the first thing which you should mention and why you can't use annotations?

Comment: AmtiK, yes I forgot to mention that, It's a legacy class.

Comment: @yuris Then you could use mix-ins. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38889775/1426227).

Comment: Well, will wait for other answers if nothing comes will accept yours.. I have a lot of pojo classes like that and creating mix classes for which one is not the best solution....

Comment: @yuris The last option is custom serialization.

Comment: this will require from to create custom class for each pojo as well, right?

Comment: @yuris You could try a generic one extending [`BeanSerializerModifier`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html). You want to avoid only serialization of protected fields? Is there any other condition?

Comment: @AmitK _How did you measure the exact number of seconds?_ Hover the comment date/time to see the seconds as well ;)

Comment: @Cássio Mazzochi Molin, when serializing ,  those fields with public setters

Answer (score 0):

You've instructed your mapper to serialize public getters:

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
```

That's why Jackson will serialize the `sn` field (You have a public getter here in the end).

To get rid of the serialized `sn` field, simply annotate your *getter* with `@JsonIgnore`:

```
public class Item{
  protected String sn;
  private String name;

  public Item(){
      sn = "43254667";
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
  @JsonIgnore
  public String getSn() {
      return sn;
  }

}
```

If you cannot annotate your class, you can always write a custom serializer for your POJO or use [Mixins](https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, can't use annotation.
Also, I can't modify the pojo class.