# Jackson deserialization - dealing with generated values with no fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a simple class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Endpoint.class)
public class Endpoint {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView({View.Endpoint.class, View.User.class})
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Phone number is required.")
    @JsonView({View.Endpoint.class, View.Call.class, View.User.class})
    private String phoneNumber;

    @JsonView({View.Endpoint.class, View.Call.class, View.User.class})
    private String callerId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonView(View.Endpoint.class)
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private User user;

    ...

    @Override
    @JsonView({View.Endpoint.class, View.Call.class, View.User.class})
    public String getUri() {
        return EndpointController.BASE_PATH + "/" + getId();
    }

}
```

I get the following error when trying to deserialize:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "uri" (class
>   com.example.server.telephony.endpoint.Endpoint), not marked as
>   ignorable (5 known properties: "id", "label", "callerId",
>   "phoneNumber", "user"])

Since URI is a generated value there is no field to annotate with `@JsonIgnore`. Any suggestions on what to do in this case?

Comment: You could consider [mix-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889775/1426227).

Comment: Try annotating getters instead of fields

Comment: when you are using @JsonIdentityInfo what is requirement to have @JsonView?!

Comment: @Generic I use `@JsonView` to avoid loops when I parse the `User` or `Endpoint` class which have a one to many relationship. Added these at different times so haven't evaluated if I need both. Does the use of `@JsonIdentityInfo` handle circular references?

Comment: @JsonIdentityInfo can handle the circular

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your `Endpoint` class using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Or configure the `ObjectMapper` with the following option to affect all POJOs deserialized with this Mapper:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```